# Is there any difference on allocating memory like this?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, heap-memory, low-level

I think i have a beginner doubt. I don't know if it is a very stupid question, but there is any difference between this two cases:

**Generic struct:**

```c
typedef struct {

    void* data;

} Object;
```

**1st case:** This case allocates memory on a pointer and then, the pointer is returned.

```c
Object* NewObject1(const void* data) {

    Object* This = (Object*)malloc(sizeof(Object));
    memcpy_s(&This->data, sizeof(void**), &data, sizeof(void**));

    return This;
}
```

**2nd case:** In this case, the memory is allocated on a pointer that was given by the user.

```c
void NewObject2(Object** This, const void* data) {

    *This = (Object*)malloc(sizeof(Object));
    memcpy_s(&(*This)->data, sizeof(void**), &data, sizeof(void**));

}
```

The result, actually, is the same:

```c
int main(){

    Object* a = NewObject1((void*)10);
    printf("a->data = %d\n", (int)a->data);

    Object* b = NULL;
    NewObject2(&b, (void*)10);
    printf("b->data = %d\n", (int)b->data);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
a->data = 10
b->data = 10
```

So my question is: There is any real difference between allocating memory as in the first case or as in the second. For example, memory safety, performance, etc.

Comment: The memory allocation is the same in both, the only difference is in one you return a pointer and the other you pass in a pointer to a pointer and set it there. There's no difference except in clarity of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two methods of returning a value the same. You can either return by value, or use a pointer argument that points to where the "returned" value should be written.

However there are several other strange things with your code:

- Instead of `memcpy_s`, you should just write `This->data = data;` and `(*This)->data = data;` respectively. And fix the const-correctness.
- `(void *)10` is probably not a valid address, this might cause a trap, bus error or other problem. (undefined behaviour if it is not the address of an actual object)
- Casting the result of malloc is redundant or worse.
- The return value of malloc should be checked.

Comment: But i am using `(void*)10` as a value, not as an address. Is this a bad habit or an error?

Comment: The C standard: "6.3.2.3:5 An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation."

Comment: Use a union if you want to store different types into the same field.

Comment: @PaulHankin or `uintptr_t` if pointers and integers are the only requirement

Comment: @M.M there is no guarantee that converting a `uintptr_t` and back preserves the value I think? Only that if you convert a `void*` to `uintptr_t` and back you get the same pointer.

Comment: @PaulHankin not sure if there is a guarantee, but it's one of those things you can pretty safely rely on a compiler to behave as expected

Comment: Not sure how you align your last comment with what you said in your answer, since the exact same concerns apply for uintptr_t as they do for any other int type - the only difference is the other way round, that converting the pointer to a uintptr_t won't lose information.

Comment: So, summarizing. The functions do the same thing, also I should delete the `const` keyword from the two functions, use the `=` instead of the `memcpy_s` and assert the result of the `malloc` (Note: I didn't do this, because it was an example). Anything else?.